# 6s battery but one fail while balance load charging. Still safe?

Tags: battery-safety, battery-cell

I have a 6s lipo battery. When I plug in for load balance charging. One of the cell is not connected, seems to be some problem with the wire of the white connector not connecting.

Any idea if this is still safe to use?

Comment: If it's just the wire used to charge the cells, I believe there's no problem as the cells are connected together, which makes one charge the other.

Comment: What if its one of the cell fails?

Comment: In this type of battery, the cells are connected in series, it will not short out internally by itself, which would be the worst case. If it "dies" and can't hold a load it will be like a resistor between the other cells, which will make the battery have a much lower voltage or it can become an "open circuit", this case the battery turn off. But as your case is the external wire of the charger, there will be no problem, it will just take longer to charge. With a multimeter measure each cell and see its ok.

Comment: Look this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0k3XLUAzwaU) to understand more.

Comment: Hi yes I checked. The voltage is lower. Battery clearly holds no charge. Its one of the cell that has no power at all. I assume this can be used anymore.

Comment: Okay, in this case I would recommend not using it with the 6 cells. But it doesn't mean that the battery is lost, you can open it and take out the damaged cell, to use it as a 5S battery.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem a while ago - I had two Robbe 6s LIPOs (4200mAh) and both had a dead cell. I'm afraid you won't be able to do anything to repair it - just buy a new LIPO from a different manufacture. It might be a bit risky to use a 5 cell 6 cell battery if your ESC is setup very sensitive (due to the loss of voltage).